# PRISM Xamarin.Forms INavigationService understanding. [Continuation]

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I wonder if the option discussed in the link below can already be made using Prism.
[PRISM Xamarin.Forms INavigationService understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43388248/prism-xamarin-forms-inavigationservice-understanding)

Project using MasterDetail.

In XF without Prism, using PushAsync, a Page opens without replacing MainPage, with NavigationBar and back button.

- App.css

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyMasterPage());
```

- Call SecondPage from MyMasterPageViewModel.cs

```
await _navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
```

The SecondPage page opens as modal and with NavigationBar and back button.
I could not reproduce this same behavior using Prism.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To start your example of what you would like to do is not how a MasterDetailPage is meant to be used. To help here I'll illustrate with a simple example. The MasterDetailPage should never be wrapped inside of a NavigationPage, but rather the Detail of the MasterDetailPage should be a NavigationPage with some page set as its content.

```
var page = new MasterDetailPage
{
    Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage())
};
```

In Prism let's assume you have a MasterDetailPage called MainPage, and you've registered the NavigationPage and a ContentPage called ViewA and another called ViewB.

The proper way of creating the MasterDetailPage would be:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage/NavigationPage/ViewA");
```

Now if you were to want to push ViewB from ViewA like:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewB");
```

You would see this pushed inside of the NavigationPage with Navigation to go back to ViewA. Now let's say that you'd like to force this to be a Modal you would simply do:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewB?useModalNavigation=true");
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for answering ...

I tried all the options I found and nothing worked as expected ...

I am trying to convert this project to PRISM ...(https://github.com/ionixjunior/YellowClone).

Comment: Note that when you select the "My Wallet" option in the menu, the "My Wallet" screen opens without the option to open the menu, but with NavigationBar and backbutton.

Comment: At PRISM, I didn't find this possibility.

Comment: There are thousands of developers successfully using Prism around the world for the last several years. The issue is not Prism. I would be happy to help you further but it appears you need my guidance as a consultant more than a simple answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: Alright, this project is just an example. It implements a MasterDetail within a NavigatioPage (MainPage = new NavigationPage (new MainView ());), so every page that is opened by PushAsync will contain the backbutton. In PRISM this is not possible, or it does not work as in XF without Prism. Thanks.